# redux-resist losing data on refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

My `App Component`

[image]

My `Store`

```js
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'; // defaults to localStorage for web
import { rootReducer } from './reducers';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
let store = createStore(persistedReducer);
let persistor = persistStore(store);
export { store, persistor };
```

[image]

`localStorage`

[image]

> After refresh / reload the `cartItems` become empty

`package info`

react: "^17.0.2",

react-redux: "^7.2.3",

redux-persist: "^6.0.0",

> I can see data being store on `localStorage` but on page refresh, i am losing the data

Comment: What happens when you add redux dev tool configuration where you `createStore(persistedReducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())`.

Answer (score 0):

Add [whitelist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist#blacklist--whitelist) to your persistConfig variable by passing "auth" only auth reducers will be persisted. you can define as many as reducers in the whitelist you want to be persisted. This should resolve your issue.

```
const persistConfig = {
     key: 'root',
     storage,
     whitelist: ["auth"] //
    };
```

Go through this npm Readme for more clarification: https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist#blacklist--whitelist